# encrypting a Document using vigenere cipher

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-symmetric, vigenere

I'm interested in learning about different encryption techniques and have started to implement a vigenere cipher in c#.  I can implement a windows forms which allows me to encrypt and decrypt a string similar the following link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533269/c-sharp-vigenere-cipher-to-encrypt-an-text-file

My question is how could I use vigenere to encrypt a word document or an image file instead of a string? I have created button which opens a dialog to let me choose a file, I'm now stuck on how to encrypt the chosen file.  Anybody have any idea's?

Comment: Every file is a string. Though not necessarily a string of ASCII or alphanumeric characters, as your code probably assumes right now.

Comment: Ok so if I try and replace say, string = "mynameispete" with the string for my document location this should work?

Comment: Well not the document *location*, but the actual document *contents* itself. You'll have to read from and write to files.

Comment: So I could use the stream reader/writer in the encryption and decryption functions?

Comment: It's probably best to keep the crypto functions separate from the reading and writing (that way, you can use the same crypto functions for things other than just files).

Comment: Ok I think I understand now, on button onclick read then word document call the encryption function then write to and save? Does that seem feasible. I can't try as I'm not at home but will be able to try tonight

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into a byte array

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\folder\myfile");
```

then feed this into your encryption routine to produce a different byte[] array to write back to disk

```
bytesEncrypted = MyEncryptFunction(bytes);
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\folder\myfile.encrypted", bytesEncrypted)
```